# pxe boot ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I need a Server which allows pxe boot Ubuntu Live CD to Client. 
I am going to make it using TFTP and DHCP. This two things are done. 
Also, using [this article](http://wellsie.net/p/286/) I am trying to boot standard Desktop ISO Image.

The difference is: I install memdisk and change path my way:

```
apt-get install syslinux-common
cp /usr/lib/syslinux/memdisk other/
```

and also in /other I put my iso.
setting of tftp is:

```
TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/var/lib/tftpboot"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure"
RUN_DAEMON="yes"
OPTIONS="-l -s /var/lib/tftpboot"
```

DHCP is raised.

/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default

```
# DISPLAY boot.txt

label wde    #without the line tftp doesn't go (??)
 #   menu default
  #  menu label WDE Recovery
  #  root (hd0,0)
    menu label ISO boot
    kernel other/memdisk
    append iso initrd=other/ubuntu.iso --
```

tree of tftpboot:

```
├── boot.txt
├── debian
│   └── etch
│       └── i386
│           ├── initrd.gz
│           └── linux
├── ldlinux.c32
├── other
│   ├── memdisk
│   └── ubuntu.iso
├── pxelinux.0
└── pxelinux.cfg
    └── default
```

But it all does not go! I see now reason why..
Screen of the Client is in attach..

Any help will be greatly appreciate.. !

[image]

I tend to think that point is in /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default
but I have no idea how I should change it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it done!
Funny, but it needed just one line in  /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default
before `label wde`must be `DEFAULT wde`.

That's it!